# java error causing Aptana not to run

Tags: ubuntu, aptana, java

> A Java Runtime Environment (JRE) or Java Development Kit (JDK) must be
>   available in order to run AptanaStudio3. No Java virtual machine was
>   found after searching the following locations: /home/hts/bin/Aptana
>   Studio 3/jre/bin/java java in your current PATH

I am getting the above error when ever i run aptana . I have Sun java and it's defined in the environment. How can i solve it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found:

```
./aptana -vm /etc/alternatives/java
```

In your installation:

```
./aptana -vm "/path/to/java/bin/directory"
```

See
[HOWTO: Install Aptana IDE](http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-315444.html)

Comment: can i specify this in some aptana file instead of running this through terminal everytime

Comment: I never use aptana so I can not help you. Create just script and add it to /usr/local/bin .