# Java Runtime Environment not found error

Tags: java, aptana

I've been working on `Aptana` Studio and some JRE required software for a bit of time now , but since yesterday something quite odd happened, as suddenly the software that requires it threw me an error `No Java virtual machine was found` . **Last thing I did before that was restoring my system files permissions** thought safe mode as I had some trouble with that , could this have anything to do with it ?

I've tried installing JRE once again , no results. However when I run

```
/Library/Internet\ Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/bin/java -version
```

I do get the following

```
java version "1.7.0_55"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_55-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.55-b03, mixed mode)
```

`Aptana` gives me the following error

```
No Java virtual machine
was found after searching the following locations:
/Applications/Aptana Studio 3/AptanaStudio3.app/Contents/MacOS/jre/bin/java
java in your current PATH
```

And other software such as `Spine` won't simply start.

My .bash_profile is the following :

```
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin:${PATH}"
PATH="/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_55.jdk/Contents/Home/bin:${PAT$
export PATH
export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_55.jdk/Contents/Home
```

The output of `echo $PATH`is the following

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_55.jdk/Contents/Home/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/git/bin
```

The output of `echo $JAVA_HOME` is the following

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_55.jdk/Contents/Home
```

And Java invocations on the terminal work.

Guidance will be highly appreciated.

[image: JRE Error]

Comment: Just change your PATH EV to include the JRE: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12089697/how-to-set-java-jdk-environment-variable-for-mac-os-x-10-8-mountain-lion

Comment: I set the JAVA_HOME environment variable as the post referred by @John  , echoed it and everything seems fine, but yet no result on runtime.

Comment: @JoelHernandez do you still get the error?

Comment: @GriffinG Java bin directory is on $PATH too, I can invoke it with no problem from the Terminal yet same issue resides.

Comment: @JoelHernandez I've just tried in my mac, and I do not have such a path : ..MacOS/jre/bin/java. And it starts just fine. weird..

Comment: Path for OsX GUI apps is strange and confusing, posted some links in my answer for those interested. :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9602704/java-error-causing-aptana-not-to-run?rq=1

Comment: Hello @AakashGoyal ,I did tried that but with no result, I posted the true solution for my issue below. Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After trying Peter's suggestion the problem persisted but now in another context : `"/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework" does not contain the JNI_CreateJavaVM symbol"`

After struggling for many hours, and reading about people with the same issue opting to re-install the entire OS , decided to examine the issue from another perspective, **the thing I first mentioned here that I believe went unnoticed was that I restored my permissions before this happening**, so what I did was the following.

1. After reading a bunch of articles about **Apple no longer providing Java support themselves** but Oracle providing it, reasoned through it and realized that perhaps paths (Often called directories) from Apple's final Java release may have not been strictly the same as the new Oracle releases, so decided to **wipe out all recent Oracle Java Runtime Environment** that I found on `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines` and **delete the Java Applet Plugin** from /Applications (Just search for it on your /Applications path) .
2. **Installed Apple's last stable release** from the following [link](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1572).
3. **Located** where **Apple** located their **Java releases** : `/System/Library/Frameworks/`
4. My particular interest was the Java Runtime Environment , so I **explored the `JavaVM` directory** on `/System/Library/Frameworks/`
5. **Found out that all Apple's JRE previous releases reside on a directory called `Versions`** that is within `/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework` directory, here's where I noticed something rare, for some reason at the moment I restored file permissions from my Disk Utility Application , **this directory was made inaccessible** (By not giving the root user permissions to access anything in itself).
6. **Went to my terminal console** and inside the `JavaVM.framework` directory **modified the permissions** to that directory to be accessible for all users by running the following command `chmod -R 777 Versions`.

After executing these actions I went straight to my JRE-Required software and attempted to open it , **success**!

Things to learn from the issue.

- Oracle's Java JDK/JRE are located in different paths from Apple's. (If you are struggling with some other issue, verify your Java version to determine your Java installation directory)
- Apple's disk utility application might define different permissions than expected for some files. (After restoring permissions verify that everything's working fine, if not this may be the cause of your problems.)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like AptanaStudio (Eclisebased right?) assumes that you have a JRE inside the Aptana directory (`/Applications/Aptana Studio 3/AptanaStudio3.app/Contents/MacOS/jre/bin/java`)

I assume that there is nothing there. Simplest way would be to symlink your existing JRE installation to that directory:

```
ln -s  /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_55.jdk/Contents/Home/jre /Applications/Aptana\ Studio\ 3/AptanaStudio3.app/Contents/MacOS/jre
```

Or you could start Aptana from the terminal and specify the path to `java` with `-vm`:

```
./aptana -vm "/path/to/java/bin/directory"
```

Environment variables that must be available to GUI applications are a bit tricky in OsX (at least in my experience).
It is possible to set global `PATH` (and other variables) in `/etc/launchd.conf`, see for example [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/16355/how-to-set-global-path-on-os-x/277034#277034) and `/etc/paths.d` see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/347286/what-are-the-various-files-that-could-have-path-declarations-for-os-x-terminal-i).

Comment: Thanks for the answer Peter, have to go on an urgent matter , as soon as I come back I'll attempt it and will let you know! (To mark the answer as correct if so).

Comment: Hello Peter! I'm afraid that the solution was not that simple, I did got to understand better the problem by applying your suggestion so I'm truly thankful! I'f you are interested on the solution, I've posted it below. Cheers!

Comment: I had the same problem with OS X Yosemite, JDK 8 and Aptana 3 - I just installed the apple Java link as well and Aptana started working. So i possibly have two JVMs running in the machine but Aptana seems to ignore the JDK 8 and only use the older version provided by Apple. This will have to ultimately be resolved by Aptana team but until then this is a workaround

Answer (score 0):

Simple Solution

For Windows: 
1.download the JAVA runtime environment x86(32bit) version else you will get an error with dll file from here http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jre8-downloads-2133155.html

2. Extract the folder out of the .tar file you downloaded.
3. Rename the JRE folder to "jre"
4. Then paste it in to  this directory 
   C:\Users\"User Name"\AppData\Roaming\Appcelerator\Aptana Studio

This worked for me

Answer (score 0):

I uninstalled all my Java JREs and JDK for Windows 10.  Then I downloaded Aptana again and let it install Java for me.  I think JAVA 8 was my problem, but this worked and I can still install the other versions again.